# Issues with the vmware vcloudPHP-5.1.2

Tags: php, vmware-tools

I'm having issues with the VMware vcloudPHP-5.1.2 API?

I downloaded the files, and uploaded to my server.  I updated the include files to the right path.

The first issue I received was:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM 
                                     in VCloud/API.php on line 129
```

Which I fixed by replacing all 34 occurences of:

```
$tagName = $Any::get_tagName();
```

with:

```
$tagName = $Any->get_tagName();
```

I then get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in VCloud/API.php on line 12932
```

that line is:

```
elseif ($child->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $nod function setVendor($Vendor) {
```

Is anyone else getting errors with the vmware api?

Comment: the code's broken. You'll have to go yell at vmware to fix it. While the `::` stuff might be somewhat innocent, there is NO way `$nod function` should have gotten committed to the repository. It's a flat-out syntax error.